# appdelegate does not conform to protocol GPPSignInDelegate

Tags: ios, swift2, google-signin

i have tried to integrate my iphone application with Google SignIn, i have successfully install Pods and integrate all dependencies with it, i am using Swift-2 and Xcode 7.2

In my appdelegate.Swift its shows a error like this appdelegate does not conform to protocol GPPSignInDelegate , i have tries to solved but i still shows an error anyone can please help to solve this issue

thanks in advance [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX8wS.png)

Comment: ⌘-click on the symbol to see the required methods to implement.

Comment: yes .. i tried but it is only shows details of the tapped content

Comment: Quick google search [GPPSignInDelegate](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/protocol_g_p_p_sign_in_delegate-p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i read on the documentation you have two methods to implement if you want to conform to the delegate :

- finishedWithAuth:error:
- didDisconnectWithError:

so in code that should look like :

```
extension AppDelegate : GPPSignInDelegate {

  func finishedWithAuth(auth: GTMOAuth2Authentication!, error: NSError!) {
  }

  func didDisconnectWithError(error: NSError!) {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is that you need  implement the method in the protocol which you write ：
the method func  you define in your  protocol